# Facebook Ads API - Can't Edit Audience

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to create custom audience & followed the instructions given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience#Creating).

This is  the code I've used.

```
  $audience = new CustomAudience(null, 'act_'.$account_id);
  $aud_data = array(
      CustomAudienceFields::NAME => $name,
      CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE => CustomAudienceSubtypes::WEBSITE,
      CustomAudienceFields::RULE => array('event' => array('i_contains' => $name ) ),
      CustomAudienceFields::PIXEL_ID => $pixelId,
      CustomAUdienceFields::DESCRIPTION => '',
      CustomAudienceFields::RETENTION_DAYS => 180,
      CustomAudienceFields::PREFILL => True
);


$audience->setData($aud_data);

$create = $audience->create();
```

The custom audience is being created successfully but on dashboard it is giving the error 'Can't Edit the Audience' as shown in screenshot below.

[image: Image I'm getting]

I don't understand this error. I'm using the latest API, why would it use old settings? Also, this is not what I want, I want to create a 'Custom Combination Audience' which is available through dashboard but not through API. Basically, I'm trying to emulate this (screenshot) through API. I'm using [PHP Ads SDK 2.5](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk)

[image: Required Image]

Answer (score 0):

1) You're rule should be a JSON string.
  `CustomAudienceFields::RULE => '{"and": [{"event": {"i_contains": "ViewContent"}},{"content_name": {"i_contains": "'.$name.'"}}]}'`

2) Facebook doesn't support that type via the current Marketing API (v2.11):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/

> Type of custom audience, derived from original data source. 
>   Note: COMBINATION subtype is only used by Power Editor and Ads Manager, and not available through the API.